# como borrar el valor de una propiedad de un objeto en nodejs

Tags: nodejs, mongoose

necesito borrar el nombre de una imagen en un objeto en nodejs. desde angular hago click en un boton para borrar una imagen. la imagen la borro del servidor pero no consigo poner en null la imagen.

```
updateImage1: function(req, res) {
    var image1 = req.body;
    console.log(image1);
    var roomId = req.body._id;
    var image1del = null;
    console.log('id', roomId);
    // Buscar y actualizar documento
    Room.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: roomId }, { image1: null }, { new: true }, (err, roomUpdated) => {

        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send({
                status: 'error',
                message: 'Error al actualizar la habitación'
            });
        }

        if (!roomUpdated) {
            return res.status(200).send({
                status: 'error',
                message: 'No se a actualizado la habitacion'
            });
        }

        // Devolver respuesta
        return res.status(200).send({
            status: 'success',
            image1: image1del
        });

    });
},
```

el objeto tiene 5 imagenes pero en este caso solo necesito poner en null la imagen1. he estado mirando la documentación de mongoose para findoneandupdate() pero no me aclaro. el método updateImage1 recibe el id del objeto Room. pero no se como poner en null la imagen1.

Answer (score 0):

Proba cambiar el Schema de imagen1 por Schema.Types.Mixed y de esa forma que tome los dos tipos. Sino deberias guardar un valor vacio ("")

[image: Schema en la base de datos]

Comment: pero como poner el valor vacio con ""?

Comment: En vez de poner null pones "". De esta forma, estas utilizando el mismo tipo de datos que requiere el schema de Mongoose